# Modify Javascript Algorithm to Solve n times m matrices using Gauss Elimination

Tags: javascript

I need help to modify an algorithm in javascript that uses Gauss Elimination to solve NxN matrices to make it solve NxM matrices. Can anyone help? Or point me in the direction of an already implemented code in javascript?

Here is the algorithm I'm using:
http://jsfiddle.net/c1x9y00d/

```
function gauss($A, $x) {
    // Just make a single matrix
    for ($i=0; $i < count($A); $i++) { 
        $A[$i].push($x[$i]);
    }
    $n = count($A);

    for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) { 
        // Search for maximum in this column
        $maxEl = abs($A[$i][$i]);
        $maxRow = $i;
        for ($k=$i+1; $k < $n; $k++) { 
            if (abs($A[$k][$i]) > $maxEl) {
                $maxEl = abs($A[$k][$i]);
                $maxRow = $k;
            }
        }


        // Swap maximum row with current row (column by column)
        for ($k=$i; $k < $n+1; $k++) { 
            $tmp = $A[$maxRow][$k];
            $A[$maxRow][$k] = $A[$i][$k];
            $A[$i][$k] = $tmp;
        }

        // Make all rows below this one 0 in current column
        for ($k=$i+1; $k < $n; $k++) { 
            $c = -$A[$k][$i]/$A[$i][$i];
            for ($j=$i; $j < $n+1; $j++) { 
                if ($i==$j) {
                    $A[$k][$j] = 0;
                } else {
                    $A[$k][$j] += $c * $A[$i][$j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Solve equation Ax=b for an upper triangular matrix $A
    $x = array_fill(0, $n, 0);
    for ($i=$n-1; $i > -1; $i--) { 
        $x[$i] = $A[$i][$n]/$A[$i][$i];
        for ($k=$i-1; $k > -1; $k--) { 
            $A[$k][$n] -= $A[$k][$i] * $x[$i];
        }
    }

    return $x;
}
```

Comment: Does [this](http://martin-thoma.com/solving-linear-equations-with-gaussian-elimination/#tocAnchor-1-4) help

Comment: It doesn't. Unfortunately that is the algorithm I'm using, but it doesn't work. I use http://matrix.reshish.com/gauss-jordanElimination.php to check if the system is consistent. My matrix is [[0,10,0],[0,0,-10],[0,-10,10],[-1,-1,-1],[1,1,1]] and my solve vector is [-9,9,0,0,0]. Help?

Comment: Using the method you suggested, the matrix I used is [[-20,20,0,-9],[20,0,-5,9],[0,-20,5,0],[-1,-1,-1,0],[1,1,1,0]], and still i can a result vector of all null